# Hibernate update entity doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate

So i have this entities:

[image: Twitch channel class]

[image: Channel command class]

And when I try to update TwitchChannel entity, using session.update(), nothing really happens. It doesn't throw an exception or log anything, code after update call doesn't get executed. I set hibernate's batch size to zero, so it shouldn't batch updates.

Update function in dao looks like this:

[image: update channel function]

channelDao.update() simply calls session.update().

Comment: It's 99% not that but once I ran into something like that `@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` -- in DAO class

Comment: Oh, code after the operation doesn't get executed? So there has to be some exception thrown. Look for `try {} catch()` blocks

Comment: How do you persist or fetch the first entity?

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk i just use session.save()

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @Pijotrek, wrapping update call in try/catch block helped and hibernate actually threw:

> Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Replacing session.update() with session.merge() solved the issue!